# what's multiprocessing spawn? Process memory is not replicated as what fork does

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

from multiprocessing `spawn`:

> The parent process **starts a fresh python interpreter process. The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run the process objects run() method**. In particular, unnecessary file descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited. Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using fork or forkserver. [Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows and macOS.]

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import signal

FOO = 10

def foo():
    assert FOO == 0

def test1():
    global FOO
    FOO = 0
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()

def bar():
    assert signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM) == signal.SIG_DFL

def test2():
    orignal = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM)
    assert orignal == signal.SIG_DFL
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    p = ctx.Process(target=bar, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test1()
    test2()
```

output:

```
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/opt/miniconda3/envs/iris-dev/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/foo/opt/miniconda3/envs/iris-dev/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/foo/Work/iris/iris2/example.py", line 7, in foo
    assert FOO == 0
AssertionError
Process SpawnProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/opt/miniconda3/envs/iris-dev/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/foo/opt/miniconda3/envs/iris-dev/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/foo/Work/iris/iris2/example.py", line 18, in bar
    assert signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM) == signal.SIG_DFL
AssertionError
```

For the first test, `FOO` in parent process state is mutated but its child doesn't see this modification.

But for the `test2`, the signal handler mutated state is reflected in both child and parent. (maybe it's C-level code???)

I know when you do fork, children should have same memory of its parent at the fork point. But is seems it's **not always** true for `spawn`

So my questions are

1. What's happening during `spawn`?
2. Why the memory state of child and parent sometimes differ while sometimes not?

---

update: I have test 3, where I register a signal handler (**python code**) in parent process, which is not replicated to children process by `spwan`

```
def bar():
    # assert this is not handler installed at parent
    assert signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM) == signal.SIG_DFL

def dummy(signum, frame):
    print("dummy", signum, frame)

def test3():
    orignal = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGTERM)
    assert orignal == signal.SIG_DFL

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, dummy)
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    p = ctx.Process(target=bar, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python relies on the `exec` primitive to implement the `spawn` start method on UNIX platforms.

When a new process is forked, the `exec` loads a new Python interpreter and points it out to the module and function you are giving as a target to your `Process` object. When the module is loaded, the `if __name__ == "__main__":` evaluates to `False`. This avoids your logic from entering an endless loop which would end up spawning infinite processes.

Assuming you are executing this code on a UNIX machine, this is the correct behaviour based on [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) specifications.

> This volume of POSIX.1-2017 specifies that signals set to SIG_IGN remain set to SIG_IGN, and that the new process image inherits the signal mask of the thread that called exec in the old process image.

This works only for `SIG_IGN`. In fact, on `test3` you can observe how your handler is reset.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `spawn` uses `exec` to loads a fresh interpreter image that **erases** everything inherited from the parent through `fork`? I should assume the new process image is **unrelated** to the parent process image anymore? I mean, a child's memory is not a mirror of the parent after exec?

Comment: Exactly. Memory, file descriptors and handlers are wiped. Nevertheless `SIG_IGN` is still inherited.